# I get this Error: Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise]

Tags: node.js, router

```
app.use('/api/auth', (req, res) => {
  console.log("AUTH");
  authRoutes(req, res, app);
});
```

```
export function authRoutes(req, res, app) {
  console.log("Auth Routes");
  app.post("/login", authController.login(req, res));
  app.post("/register", authController.register);
  app.post("/password/forgot", authController.forgotPassword);
  app.post("/password/new", authController.newPassword);
  app.post("/tfa", authController.tfa);
  app.post("/logout", authController.logout);
}
```

```
export const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    const user =await Users.findOne({
      username: req.body.username,
      active: "active"
    });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send({ message: "Username doesn't exist or account is not active!" });
    }

    const passwordIsValid = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);

    if (!passwordIsValid) {
      return res.status(401).send({ message: "Invalid username or password!" });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, secret, { expiresIn: 86400 });

    req.session.token = token;

    sendMessage(user.email, "New Login to your Account!", "If this was you then you can just delete this email but if it wasn't you, please contact us as quick as possible.");

    res.setHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    res.status(200).send({
      id: user._id,
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Internal server error." });
  }
}
```

So this is what I have but when I run the server and make the post login request I get the Error I have put into the Title.

```
export function authRoutes(req, res, app) {
  console.log("Auth Routes");
  app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    authController.login(req, res);
  });
  app.post("/register", authController.register);
  app.post("/password/forgot", authController.forgotPassword);
  app.post("/password/new", authController.newPassword);
  app.post("/tfa", authController.tfa);
  app.post("/logout", authController.logout);
}
```

This is what I tried doing but then I don't get any errors but it also doesn't call the function? Do you have any solutions for my Problem I tried so many different solutions and they all so far didn't work.

Comment: Your solution should work. It probably doesn't call the function because you didn't send `post` request to `/login` endpoint

Comment: I actually did but when I try my solution it doesn't do anything.